# How to list relationed objects on QGIS expression for HTML tips

Tags: qgis, relation

I have two layers with an 1-N relationship

The parent layer, "RADAR" is a point layer, while the child layer, "FAIXA_RADAR" is a tabular without geometry layer.

To make feature data consultation easier, I made an HTML code to use in *tips*, returning main information about that feature.

```
<html>
    <style>
    body {
                    width: 1000px;
                    height: 100%;
                    margin: 12px;
                    padding: 12px;
                    overflow-y: scroll;
                    overflow-x: scroll;
                    text="#000000"
    }

    p {
        font-family: "Verdana";
    }
    html {
      overflow-y: scroll;
       overflow-x: scroll;
    }

    </style>
    
    <body>
    <div style="width:1000;height: 300px">
        <div id="cabecalho">
        <h2>[% "status" %] - [% "nome" %]</h2>
        </div>
        <div id="corpo">
        <ul style="list-style-type: none; padding: 0; margin: 0;">
        [% CASE WHEN "tipo" IS NOT NULL  THEN '<li><b>Tipo:</b> ' || "tipo" || '</li>' ELSE '' END ||
        CASE WHEN "data_operacao_inicial" IS NOT NULL  THEN '<li><b>Data de Operação Inicial:</b> ' || format_date("data_operacao_inicial",'dd/MM/yyyy') || '</li>' ELSE '' END
        %]
        </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="url"style="margin-top: 10px">
        <ul style="list-style-type: none; padding: 0; margin: 0;">
        <li><a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=&layer=c&cbll=[% y(transform($geometry,'EPSG:31983','EPSG:4326')) %],[% x(transform($geometry,'EPSG:31983','EPSG:4326')) %]&cbp=11,0,0,0,0"><b>Street View</b></a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        
        <div id="responsavel"style="margin-top: 10px">
        <small>
        <ul style="list-style-type: none; padding: 0; margin: 0;">
        <li>[% CASE WHEN "criado_por" IS NOT NULL  THEN '<b>Criação: </b> ' || "criado_por" ELSE '' END ||
        CASE WHEN "criado_em" IS NOT NULL  THEN ' (' || format_date("criado_em", 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm') || ')' ELSE '' END %]</li>
        <li>[% CASE WHEN "atualizado_por" IS NOT NULL  THEN '<b>Última atualização: </b> ' || "atualizado_por" ELSE '' END ||
        CASE WHEN "atualizado_em" IS NOT NULL  THEN ' (' || format_date("atualizado_em", 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm') || ')' ELSE '' END %]</li>
        </ul>
        </small>
        </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image]

This feature showed on image, for exemple, have relatioship with 4 features from "Faixa - Radar" layer

[image]

I wonder if it is possible to return and iterate all features on the child layer to make an HTML table.
The only workaround I thought was using javascript/Ajax and making a direct connection with database, but I am searching for a solution using only QGIS expressions tools.

Desired result:

(Each line in table is a feature on child layer)

[image]